# How to remove the whole float numbes in my text usig PHP

Tags: php

How to remove all the float numbers in my variable?

- This is my variable:
  $var = "test1 1200.980 test2 1234.00 test3 1400.0008";
- I want that php display in the browser to me this Result : test1 test2 test3
  #thanks for helping.

Comment: Requirements-only questions are usually not received well here.  Can you include your current PHP script?

Comment: I don't have any script, i just have a variable has a big text, this text has a lot of float numbers, so i want to remove these float numbers from my text

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, using `preg_replace`:

```php
$var = "test1 1200.980 test2 1234.00 test3 1400.0008";
$output = trim(preg_replace("/\s*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b\s*/", " ", $var));
echo $var . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
test1 1200.980 test2 1234.00 test3 1400.0008
test1 test2 test3
```